Same Material on Different Objects Looks Different in the Scene
I've applied the same material to two different objects and the results are different. The character's skin on the left looks correct.  The character's skin on the right is too bright, like it's over exposed. 

First, check for flipped normals. If that isn’t it, add a screenshot of your node setup.

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Actually it looks fine in rest mode, but in pose mode it looks wrong.  Does that make any sense?

Here is the Blender file... https://we.tl/t-vdSPXKUlze
